# will coping files recursively from one directory to another lead to changes in one directory reflect in another directory files also?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

If I copy files from one directory to another directory:

- Will their inode numbers also change?
- Changes in file of one directory, will it reflect in same file of another directory also?

When I use command like:

```
cp -r dir1/ dir2/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple copy the file system handle the copied files as newly created ones, therefore assining new inodes to them. 
Any change made in the origin wouldn't change the copys. This only happens when you create symbolic or hard links between files.

You can check the inodes of your files with "ls -i filename".